# Non-linear curve fitting -- fitnlm and lsqcurvefit give different error values

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I'm trying to perform a non-linear fit for a biological binding experiment. I have been using the lsqcurve fit feature in MATLAB and have been a little disappointed with the large confidence interval given how well the fit looks. For comparison, I tried the fitnlm algorithm and I get the same fit values with a considerably smaller confidence interval.

I'm new to MATLAB and don't have a strong statistics background. Why would the two algorithms give the same fit with  different confidence intervals? Or am I confusing what the two values represent? Am I justified in using the NLM algorithm simply because it works better? Thanks for any insights and things to consider! Code copied below.

LSQCURVE Method

```
% Two state binding model
fun = @(x,xdata)(x(1)-x(2))*(xdata./(x(3)+xdata))-x(2);

% Parameterize 
x0 = [max(F), min(F), mean(C)];

% Perform the fit. In order to calculate confidence intervals, the full
% lsqcurvefit results are returned. Beta holds the fit values.

[beta,resnorm,resid,exitflag,output,lambda,J] = lsqcurvefit(fun,x0,xdata,ydata);
ci = nlparci(beta,resid,'jacobian',J);
beta(3) % Kd (parameter of interest)
beta(3)-ci(3) % Kd error
```

FIT NLM Method

```
fun = @(b,x)((b(1)-b(2))*(x./(b(3)+x))-b(2));

% Parameterize 
b0 = [max(F), min(F), mean(C)];

% Perform the fit. 
nlm = fitnlm(C,F,fun,b0)

beta = nlm.Coefficients.Estimate;
beta_error = nlm.Coefficients.SE;

beta(3) % Kd
beta_error(3) % Kd error
```

Sample Data (Column 1 is X or Concentration (C); Column 2 is Y or Fluorescence (F))

```
1.0e+04 *

    1.0000    5.6787
    0.5000    5.0545
    0.2500    4.4922
    0.1250    3.5727
    0.0625    2.5402
    0.0312    1.4649
    0.0156    0.6791
    0.0078    0.3283
    0.0039    0.1652
    0.0020    0.0958
    0.0010    0.0291
    0.0005    0.0274
```

Comment: Each function uses a different estimation algorithm by default. See the manual pages for [`lsqcurvefit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqcurvefit.html) (especially section "Algorithm") and [`nlinfit`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/nlinfit.html) (the `fitnlm` page points the reader to `nlinfit`). Also see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22547428/fitnlm-or-lsqcurvefit-for-non-linear-least-squares-regression

Comment: Hi Vicky, thanks for the response. I did try the Levenberg–Marquardt algorithm with the lsqcurvefit function, but that didn't seem to help...

Comment: I just compared `ci = nlparci(...)` against `nlm.coefCI()` and the results are the same for me. You are not by any chance comparing confidence intervals (well, the estimated coefficients minus the lower end of the intervals) against standard errors as your code seems to suggest, are you? (BTW, I reproduced your example in R with `nls`, and the results were the same.)

Comment: Good point - I think I'm conflating confidence interval and standard error. I'm after the standard error of the measurement, and it seems ```fitnlm``` is better suited for this according to this article: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/97489-is-it-possible-to-generate-standard-error-estimates-for-the-parameters-generated-by-lsqcurvefit. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Good approximates for the parameters b1 , b2 , b3 can be obtained  with the very simple method below (no trial and error ).

If the result is not accurate enough one can use those approximates as initial values (instead of guesses) to start an iterative method such as you already tried. This guarantees a better convergence.

[image]